# "has_many through" is breaking user post creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have a forum where I have Posts, Users and Looks (the Looks controls read/unread state of posts):

```
class User
  has_many :posts, through: :looks
  has_many :comments
  has_many :looks
end

class Post
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :looks
  has_many :users, through: :looks
end

class Look
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is the posts_controller:

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

And finally the haml:

```
- unless @post.user.blank?
    .profileImage{:style => "background: url(#{@post.user.image_url)}"}
    %span.userName= @post.user.username
    %span.userTitle= @post.user.custom_title
    %span.userCount
      = @post.user.posts.count + @post.user.posts.count
      posts
```

---

The problem is that the line `through :looks` in the user model results in user attributes not being saved to the post when created. The post user seems to be blank. Even if I remove the `through :looks` line and refresh, the user info doesn't show up.

If I remove the `through :looks` line it works: the user info shows up and all is good. But then obviously the Looks functionality doesn't work.

Also, if I just remove the `- unless @post.user.blank?`, I get a `undefined method image_url`
 error when trying to create a post.

How can I make `through :looks` work with my current setup?

EDIT:

To clarify, the user_id is not being included in the post creation if I have `has_many :posts, through :looks`

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly using the `has_many :through` association.

In your setup, the association a user has with a post goes through a look. This means a post does not have a foreign key going directly to the user. This foreign key would be the `user_id` attribute.

When you try to build the post with `current_user.posts.build(post_params)` it assumes there is no `user_id` since the association is going through a look. That is why it does not assign a value to `user_id`.

When you delete the `:through` option, it then looks for a `user_id` to assign since this is a direct association. If you want to stick with the `through` option, you would remove `belongs_to :user` from the `Post` model and the `user_id` from the `Post` migration.

I suggest [reading more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) about the `has_many :through` association. Good luck!